# wordpress 404 - once to 404 and once to home page

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with the 404 in my site.
I didn't build the site, just fixing some issues there.

I'm using the default permalink structure, and have a 404.php in my theme folder.
My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is:
when I change the URL to `/?page_id="page number that doesn't exist"` - I get the 404 page,
but when I just write some letters (e.g. `/sjkhdk`) I get the home page (I want them both to get to the 404 page).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: is the WP up to date? What version is it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have issues with permalinks, this process *usually* sorts it out.

1. Make sure .htaccess is writable by the webserver.
2. Go to `Settings>Permalinks` and simply hit Save Changes. This will reset the wordpress permalinks internally.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Did you try this out @user1629677?